# How to convert binary image to RGB with PIL?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, opencv, python

I have PIL Image in binary and I need to convert it in RGB. I did this diskew image

binary image

[image]

I need this way:

[image]

I already tried this which is not working

```
from PIL import Image as im

img = im.fromarray((255 * Image).astype("uint8")).convert("RGB")
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you trying to invert the image and make all blacks into whites and all whites in to blacks? Or are you trying to rotate the image to make it skew? Or are you trying to add an Alpha/Transparency layer for no good reason to an image that doesn't have one?

Comment: I did skew on the Image so I got result into binary form which looks as above. and Now I want to convert it into RGB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I still don't understand why you convert to RGBA if you want RGB, but this code converts your image to RGB as you ask:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open input image
im = Image.open('text.png').convert('RGB')

# Invert
npim = 255 - np.array(im)

# Save
Image.fromarray(npim).save('result.png')
```

[image]